How to save session in pywebview?
I have a simple python program that opens a website, made in pywebview. I want that if I log in to the site, the next time I start it I won’t have to log in again.
import webview

# WINDOW
window = webview.create_window('Simple Browser', 'https://mail.google.com/')
icon_path = 'D:\Projects\Blender Add-on\logo.ico'
window.icon = icon_path
# START
webview.start()



Just put private_mode as False in webview.start(), all session is stored at %appdata%\pywebview in windows or ~/.pywebview in linux
import webview

# WINDOW
window = webview.create_window('Simple Browser', 'https://mail.google.com/')
icon_path = 'D:\Projects\Blender Add-on\logo.ico'
window.icon = icon_path
# START
webview.start(private_mode=False)


window.icon = 'logo.ico' is not working can you please help me.

@Philip Just in the icon_path string use "\" and not "" like this: icon_path = 'D:\Projects\Blender Add-on\logo.ico'
